# How to rebuild a widght on demand

Tags: flutter

so i have a set of text widgets that checks if the passwords textfields are equal to each other or if they have lower case letters etc....

but the problem is that they are not working, nothing gets rebuilt even though the conditions are right.

and yeah I'm using Getx..

```
        Obx(
          () => setPasswordController.topPasswordController.value.text ==
                  setPasswordController.bottomPasswordController.value.text
              ? Text(
                  'Both passwords must match.',
                  style: TextStyleConstants.montserratMediumTwelveHint.copyWith(
                    color: ColorConstants.black,
                  ),
                ).paddingOnly(
                  bottom: 11,
                )
              : Text('My name jeff'),
        ),
```

Comment: you need to use setState to rebuild the UI

Comment: Use StatefulWidget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html instead relying on getx.

Comment: how to use setState in this case? I'm not just changing the color I'm adding a widget